# Angular 1 - why isn't my model data appearing in the view?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using Angular 1.6 and I can't get my data to display in my view. I know my controller is working because when the view loads, it logs the data to the console as I asked it to in vm.getFeed().

Here's my relevant code.

--routes.js--

```
myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider

  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeController',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  })

});
```

--controller.js--

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  function HomeController($http, $resource) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/pics/top/.json";

    vm.getFeed = function() {
      $http.get(vm.url)
        .then(function(response) {
          vm.feed = response.data.data.children;
          console.log(vm.feed);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.log('Error: ', err);
        });
    };

    vm.getFeed();

  }

  myApp.controller('HomeController', ['$http', '$resource', HomeController]);

}) ();
```

--index.html (body tag contents)--

```
    Main

    <div class="container">
      <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
```

--pages/home.html--

```
Home

<div>
  <li ng-repeat="item in vm.feed">
    test
  </li>
</div>
```

The feed is a 25-length array, so it should display "test" 25 times after "Main" and "Home". But here's all that gets displayed:

```
Main
Home
```

But the array gets logged to the console, so know that $http is working properly and the vm.getFeed() function is getting hit.

What am I missing?

Comment: do you have duplicate entries in feed ?

Comment: Try this > homecontroller.$injection = ["something"]; app.controller('name', homecontroller);

Comment: Hey @Maher, where do I put that line?

Comment: @Mistalis That doesn't work either - the problem isn't the <li> tag because if I change it to <li ng-repeat="item in [1,2,3]"> it prints 3 times.

Comment: Bottom of homeController function.

Comment: I'm on mobile right now, I will answer u as soon as possible.

Comment: @Maher ok, i'm confused because my controller already has this at the end:   myApp.controller('HomeController', ['$http', '$resource', HomeController]);

Comment: Where you use your controller try to do this `ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm"` and when you want to access your datas `{{vm.myData}}`

Comment: Thanks @JeanJacques - that appears to work (or at least `ng-controller="HomeController as vm"` works). But I don't understand why putting     `controller: 'HomeController',
    controllerAs: 'vm'` in my `routes.js` file doesn't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

--controller.js--

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  function HomeController($scope, $http, $resource) {

   var url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/pics/top/.json";

    $scope.getFeed = function() {
      $http.get(url)
        .then(function(response) {
          $scope.feed = response.data.data.children;
          console.log($scope.feed);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.log('Error: ', err);
        });
    };

    $scope.getFeed();

  }

  myApp.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$http', '$resource', HomeController]);

}) ();
```

--pages/home.html--

```
<div>
  <li ng-repeat="item in feed">
    test
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks David - that might work but I know that $scope is out of favor these days and that vm is the preferred way to go.

Comment: if you want your use your data on the view(HTML files), you need the set that data under your scope